# primefaces galleria sometimes not showing in IE8 and IE9

Tags: jsf, primefaces, image-gallery

I'm using a p:galleria (primefaces 3.2) and it works fine in FF and chrome. But sometimes it is not showing in IE9 and IE8 is never showing it.

IE9: When I clear browser cache and reload the page, the gallery is shown correctly. But when I then reload the page, the gallery isn't showing. I need to clear the browser cache and then it is shown again.

Here is the galleria code

```
<f:view
<ui:composition    
<ui:define name="content">
<f:view>
<f:subview id="fleetvehicleinfo">
<h:form 
.
.
<p:galleria value="#{vehicleRemarketingDetail.vehicle.Pictures_Set}" var="picture" panelWidth="470" panelHeight="350" frameWidth="110" frameHeight="80" >  
        <p:graphicImage value="/vehicle/remarketing/image/#{picture.document_id}.jpg" height="350" width="470" />
    </p:galleria>
    </h:form>
    </f:subview>
    </f:view>
</ui:define>
```

Anybody having a clue what is wrong and how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in the beginning of your header :

```
<f:facet name="first">
      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
</f:facet>
```